# Need help with relation properties using logical operators

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, relations, predicate-logic

I was wondering how should I proceed to determine what will be in the relation and what will not given these properties. Operating with integers:

$R: \{(a, b)|(a= 0∧b= 0)∨ GCD(a, b) = 5\}$

Answer (score 0):

R = { (a, b) : (a = 0 ∧ b = 0) ∨ exists coprime j,k with (a = 5j ∧ b = 5k) }

{ x : P(x) or Q(x) } = { x : P(x) } $\cup$ { x : Q(x) }

Comment: So this means the relation properties will be based on both of these definitions?

Comment: This means that $R$ will be the union of two sets representing the two cases, @john5